# Xpath preserving break lines and other html tags

Tags: php, dom, xpath, web-scraping

Below is the source of html page:

```
<h3>Background</h3>
<p>Example 1<br>Example 2<br> </br> <ul></li>ABC<li></ul>
</p>
<h3>Job Description</h3>
<p>content of job description</p>
```

This is xpath query:

```
//node()[preceding::h3[text()="Background"] and following-sibling::h3[text()="Job Description"]]
```

I need this output:

```
<p>Example 1<br>Example 2<br> </br> <ul></li>ABC<li></ul>
    </p>
```

Comment: Please post all relevant HTML. Obviously, there must be something with "Job Description" you omitted.

Comment: The query you proposed is returning exactly this output. If it isn't, that's probably because the HTML parser you're using is parsing the messy HTML another way (closing list item tag before the opening one). How are you parsing the HTML, and what happens if you dump the parsed HTML?

Comment: @JensErat It doesn't return all the tags. <p>, <ul> tags are return but the rests: <li> and <br> are missing. It appears like this: `<p>Example 1Example 2<ul>ABC</ul>
    </p>`

Comment: Your query should actually return exactly one node, the paragraph containing the whole subtree. You don't have an issue with your XPath expression, but with the parsed HTML. [Try to "repair" it](http://www.php.net/manual/de/tidy.repairstring.php) before parsing it as HTML, you might be more lucky afterwards.

Comment: @JensErat I saved the source page and repaired. I tried the cleaned file but still same result. Here is the source page link: `http://www.acbar.org/display-job/49262`

Comment: That page does not fit the example HTML above at all. What paragraph do you want to extract? For future questions, please have a look at how to post a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org), including all relevant (but minimal) data and code snippets, best would be in a form that allows to directly copy, paste and execute it.

Comment: @JensErat The paragraph under `<h3>Background</h3>`

Comment: Then select the first paragraph after the headline: `//h3[.='Background']/following-sibling::p[1]`. To be more general, you could even select the first following element, which could also be an unsorted list: `//h3[.='Background']/following-sibling::*[1]`

Comment: Bu the way, your original query works totally fine for me and returns the expected output, the problem probably is somewhere in your PHP code. Anyway: I think your `nodelist2string` method is just replicating [`c14n` method](http://www.php.net/manual/ro/domnode.c14n.php).

Comment: @JensErat I will check PHP code. Will the `descendant-or-self` work in this case? If yes, How we can use it with preceding in my query?

Comment: I don't see any fit for it, it will query the subtree, but the paragraph is not in the subtree of the header tag.

Answer (score 0):

With simple you would need to do something like:

```
$html = str_get_html($str);

foreach($html->find('h3') as $h3){
  if($h3->text() == 'Background'){
    echo $h3->next_sibling();
  }
}
// <p>Example 1<br>Example 2<br> </br> <ul></li>ABC<li></ul>  </p>
```

You can't get there with `Dom` or `Xpath` because the html is too invalid (`ul`'s inside of `p`'s)

Comment: The ul tag is fetching but not li under ul. I test this with other page and the ul is not under p but still not working. What It is same with table tags, I can get <table> tag but not child tags of table.

Answer (score 0):

This line fixed the code. It now preserved break line tag and `<li>` tag.

```
//node()[preceding::h3[text()="Background"] and following-sibling::h3[text()="Job Description"]]/node()'
```

I have added /node() at the end of the string.